# java Array.utils , it doesn't actually delete the object

Tags: java

Problems with ArrayUtils.remove(array, i)
It doesn't actually remove the object of any index. Any other solution to solve this problem?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;


public class Testing {


public static void deleteItem(ItemTracker[] listItems) {
    System.out.println("Which item you want to delete? ");
    for(int i=0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Quantity")) {
                // Some Code
            } else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Something"){
                ArrayUtils.remove(listItems, i); //  This is the part where it should delete .. but it doesnt delete. 
            } 
            break;
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: Since your code is already working, this question would probably be better suited for Stack Exchange's [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `ArrayUtils` will not be able to modify the callers array reference; Java arrays are not dynamic data structures.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/index.html):

> This method returns a new array with the same elements of the input array except the element on the specified position. The component type of the returned array is always the same as that of the input array.

You probably want:

```
listItems = ArrayUtils.remove(listItems, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to implement the equals and hashCode methods on your ItemTracker object. These are required for object-matching in collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my method instead:

```
private static <T>T[] copyArrayWithOneElementDeleted(final T[] array, final int index) {
    final int l = array.length - 1;
    if (index == l) return Arrays.copyOf(array, l);
    final T[] copy = (T[]) Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), l);
    if (index == 0) System.arraycopy(array, 1, copy, 0, l);
    else {
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, copy, 0, index);
        System.arraycopy(array, index + 1, copy, index, l - index);
    }
    return copy;
}
```

[Source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17801415#17801415)

It can be used like this:

```
listItems = copyArrayWithOneElementDeleted(listItems, i);
```